# ICS Android with 3.3 Kernel fails during init

Tags: android, kernel, android-source

I have built ICS and want to get it running on my hardware with version 3.3 of the Linux Kernel.

When the board boots up Android starts the init process but all processes get killed, with messages similar to:

```
[    7.600000] init: waitpid returned pid 2228, status = 0000000b
[    7.600000] init: process 'vold', pid 2228 exited
[    7.600000] init: process 'vold' killing any children in process group
```

Finally the board gives up with the message:

```
[   28.090000] init: critical process 'servicemanager' exited 4 times in 4 minutes; rebooting into recovery mode
```

I have tried putting logcat into my init.rc but it never appears to reach or successfully load logcat, so I can't get more detailed log information out of the device.

In my kernel config I have set ANDROID_BINDER_IPC, ASHMEM, ANDROID_LOGGER, ANDROID_TIMES_OUTPUT, ANDROID_LOW_MEMORY_KILLER and ANDROID_SWITCH. IS there something else I have missed. I was hoping after reading http://kernelnewbies.org/Linux_3.3#head-b733d694037e0b34ad47e1b5d38ebc4d1bd1d89f that with Kernel 3.3 it would be easier to get Android up and running.

Has anyone seen this issue before or can anyone help me get more log data?

Many thanks in advance,

Markus

Comment: Even with a lot of the drivers back in mainline staging, you may still need to do more than set config options.  Anyway, I'd be tempted to try to set it up to start a root shell on the console or serial (or get adbd up) rather than trying to start all of the userspace runtime.  Then you can try to start the runtime pieces manually from the shell and figure out where it is failing.

Comment: Thanks @Chris. At the moment the init.rc doesn't reach the prompt for the console. All services crash before that can run. Can I strip down the init.rc to just the console? I'll give it a try anyway when I get back in tomorrow and feedback what works/doesn't.

Comment: Yes, you don't need most of those android services to have a working "embedded linux" as a milestone. Especially if you still have a console serial port driver for that board or something left over from before you Android-ified the kernel.  For that matter you could probably boot your pre-Android filesystem just to make sure the kernel more or less works.

Comment: Still looking into this issue. I have been able to boot my board with debian on top of the kernel and going back to my android ICS build the init can launch adbd. It still fails on all other process launches, including logcat - which means I am limited to dmesg for my log/debug data. Any advise on how for force user space log data to dmesg without logcat?

Comment: You could change the logging library to do something else.  But if logcat is failing to run, maybe that itself would be a good avenue down which to debug - it's a fairly small native executable without all of the dalvik/android service etc stuff to contend with.  Do you have the kernel log driver working?  Do you have the log device file, with suitable permissions?